# complex variables in xslt template v1, v2

Tags: xslt

I have source xml looking like this :

```
<Data>
 <ActionPlaces>
   <ActionPlace>
        <ActionPlaceID>74</ActionPlaceID>
        <PlaceName>Theatre Of Classic</PlaceName>
   </ActionPlace>  
 </ActionPlaces>
 <Actions>
  <CommonAction Id="2075" Name="King">
      <Action>
         <ActionID>4706</ActionID>
         <ActionPlaceID>74</ActionPlaceID>
       </Action>
  </CommonAction>
 </Actions>
</Data>
```

Which is to transform to this:

```
<category name="King">
 <name>King</name>
 <parent name="Theatre Of Classic" />
</category>
```

I want to use variable :

```
<xsl:template match="ActionPlaces">
 <xsl:variable name="id" select="/ActionPlace/ActionPlaceID"/>

<xsl:template match="CommonAction" > 
 <category name="<xsl:value-of select="@name"/> >
    <name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name> 
    <parent <xsl:if test="/Action/ActionPlaceID = $id">
    name=/Action/ActionPlaceID/> <- how to get name of theatre here?
</xsl:template>
```

Can variable store not only id but name also? And how to get it? What is the most common approach to handle this ?

Comment: When you ask a question related to XSLT, please indicate which version you use. Would this be `XSLT 1.0` or `XSLT 2.0`?

Comment: You should use a **key** to get "related" data. -- Please note that your input XML is missing a root element.

Comment: Can u provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using XSL keys (as @michael-hor257k suggested):

#### Input

```
<Root>
  <ActionPlaces>
    <ActionPlace>
      <ActionPlaceID>74</ActionPlaceID>
      <PlaceName>Theatre Of Classic</PlaceName>
    </ActionPlace>
  </ActionPlaces>
  <Actions>
    <CommonAction Id="2075" Name="King">
      <Action>
        <ActionID>4706</ActionID>
        <ActionPlaceID>74</ActionPlaceID>
      </Action>
    </CommonAction>
  </Actions>
</Root>
```

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Collect all <ActionPlace> elements into an XSL key -->
  <xsl:key name="ActionPlaceById" match="ActionPlace" use="ActionPlaceID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Actions/CommonAction"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CommonAction">
    <category name="{@Name}">
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </name>

      <!--
      Using the ActionPlaceById key we created earlier, fetch the <ActionPlace>
      element that has an <ActionPlaceID> child that has the same value as the
      <ActionPlaceID> descendant of the current <CommonAction> element.
      -->
      <parent name="{key('ActionPlaceById', Action/ActionPlaceID)/PlaceName}"/>
    </category>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category name="King">
  <name>King</name>
  <parent name="Theatre Of Classic"/>
</category>
```

Comment: Yes, but one limit for using name="{key('ActionPlaceById', Action/ActionPlaceID)/PlaceName} is that when I try to use it ontherway -like <name><xsl:value-of select="{key('ActionPlaceById', Action/ActionPlaceID)/PlaceName}/></name>  - there mistake comes - is there any walkaround?

Comment: The curly braces indicate an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#attribute_value_templates) — you can't use them there. Try removing them: `<name><xsl:value-of select="key('ActionPlaceById', Action/ActionPlaceID)/PlaceName"/></name>`.

Comment: ok, accepted. Could u comment on my new issue xslt - strange thing when place root tag out of the <xsl:template> please?